# I have installed gitlab on a VM , with the disk of 300GB however its showing only 50GB?

Tags: gitlab

I have created a Linux vm on FreeNAS with an HDD size of 300GB but 
In system Info it's showing 50GB in rootfs

here is the screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCyT6.jpg)

How can i increase the 50GB to higher?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on this site and would be better suited for [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/) or [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) (check the autorized topics by yourself). Meanwhile, my advice: your total disk space is more or less the one your are expecting (230GB on /home and 50GB on /). So it looks like you need to understand what are partitions, how they are mounted and how to configure gitlab installation paths. You should read about all these subjects and experiment before asking a question on those sites.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for informing.

As the question here I will post the solution if anyone is looking it

This requires you to be able to ssh into the instance using the root user account and that no services be running as users out of /home on the target machine.

The examples are from a default installation with no customation-you NEED to know what you're working with for volumes/partitions to not horribly break things.

By default, CentOS 7 uses XFS for the file system and Logical Volume Manager (LVM), creating 3 partitions: /,/home and

Step 1 - Copy /home Contents
To backup the contents of /home, do the following:

```
mkdir /temp
cp -a /home /temp/
```

Once that is finished at your back at the prompt, you can proceed to step 2.

Step 2 - Unmount the /home directory

```
umount -fl /home
```

Step 3 - Note the size of the home LVM volume
We run the lvs command to display the attributes of the LVM volumes

```
lvs
```

Sample output:

> LV   VG Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
>
> home cl -wi-a----- 406.94g
>
> root cl -wi-ao----  50.00g
>
> swap cl -wi-ao----   7.81g

Step 4 - Remove the home LVM volume

```
lvremove /dev/cl/home
```

Step 5 - Resize the root LVM volume
Based on the output of lvs above, I can safely extend the root LVM by 406GiB.

```
lvextend -L+406G /dev/cl/root
```

Step 6 - Resize the root partition

```
xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/cl-root
```

Step 7 - Copy the /home contents back into the /home directory

```
cp -a /temp/home /
```

Step 8 - Remove the temporary location

```
rm -rf /temp
```

Step 9 - Remove the entry from /etc/fstab
Using your preferred text editor, ensure you open `/etc/fstab` and remove the line for

Step 10 - Don't miss this!
Run the following command to sync systemd up with the changes.

```
dracut --regenerate-all --force
```

Credit : troyfontaine(github)
Source : https://gist.github.com/troyfontaine/87091bd6a5c68f45dd62ced3d12bc377